# How to use unicode for the checkbox in customize buffers (**not** in org mode)?

Tags: customize, widget

I'm trying to modify the appearance of customize buffers. I managed to modify the button but I did not find how to change the appearance of the checkbox nor the dropdown indicator (▽). Ideally I would like to replace them with corresponding unicode glyphs. You can see what is the "real" character using `describe-char` but I'm a bit clueless on where the translation into images occurs and how to modify it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkboxes can be disabled using: `(setq widget-image-enable nil)` and will appear as `[ ]` or `[X]` that can be then prettified:

```
(setq widget-image-enable nil)
(add-hook 'custom-mode-hook (lambda ()
   "Beautify custom checkbox symbol"
   (push '("[ ]" . "☐") prettify-symbols-alist)
   (push '("[X]" . "☑" ) prettify-symbols-alist)
   (prettify-symbols-mode)))
```